# ListBox with horizontally aligned resizable objects

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a collection of images that are aligned horizontally. The containing `ListBox` fills the parent control completely. Now the images should be resized, by resizing of the parent control. I think the `ListBoxItem` dosn't resize its own height to fit the size of the `ListBox`.

**My code of the ListBox**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Pages}"
         VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
         KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False"
         Height="Auto" MinHeight="120">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=PageThumbnail}" Stretch="Uniform/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Could it be because of the `MinHeight` property set to 120?

Comment: Why should the `MinHeight` property of the `ListBox` effect the resizing of the `ListBoxItems`, if I make the window bigger? ô_O I will test it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `StackPanel` in the `ItemsPanelTemplate` with:

```
<UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
```

Then add this attribute to your `ListBox`:

```
HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
```

EDIT: posting an example, no items binding applied.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox 
     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
     KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <Image Source="o0.gif" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <Image Source="o1.gif" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        <Image Source="o2.gif" Stretch="Uniform"/>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Could you please post the complete ListBox XAML?

Comment: @Clemens I've posted an example.

Comment: Even if it would work, all cells in a UniformGrid would be the same size. What about images with different aspect ratios, e.g. landscape vs portrait?

Comment: I have tried it and it works correctly for me, assuming that the result is what the author wanted. http://i.imgur.com/QymcH.png http://i.imgur.com/QIboo.png

Comment: What about my other comment, the equal cell size? And did you also try to resize your window? Do the images shrink when you decrease the window size?

Comment: @Clemens I've been looking into it a little bit and I don't think it can be done with the standard WPF controls. Maybe you could achieve that by using a custom control.

Comment: @Clemens The same result can be achieved by disabling the vertical and/or scrollbar visibility of the `ListBox` (depending on what's the desired effect).

Comment: Ok, but you haven't shown that in your answer. And still the equal cell size of the UniformGrid would be a no go for me. If you disable the vertical scrollbar, it works perfectly with a horizontal StackPanel.

Comment: I haven't shown it in my answer because I didn't figure it out until you invited me to look more into it. If you wish you could edit out your post to include this other solution.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is simply to disable the vertical ScrollBar of the ListBox. No need to set any `HorizontalContentAlignment` or `VerticalContentAlignment`. Also no need to set `Stretch="Uniform"` on the Image control, since that is the default value.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ...>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>                
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding PageThumbnail}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```